# Regular query results in syntax error with specific attribute

Tags: postgresql, postgis, imposm

I run a postgres database with postgis extention. With imposm3 openstreetmap data is loaded into the scheme import. The tables are called osm_point, osm_linestring and osm_polygon.
Imposm is *storing NULL as empty fields*.

To query a specific attribute of the table, I usually write

`select * from import.osm_point where highway <> ''`

But only with the attribute `natural` this query is not working.

As seen in this picture, the attribute `natural` contains some filled lines and some empty lines.

[image: query to show all stored entries]

When running a query to select only `natural` without empt field, the following is happen.

````
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<>"
LINE 1: select * from import.osm_point where natural <> ''
                                                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 46```
````

Comment: `natural` is a reserved keyword. Wrap some double quotes around that and give it another go.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem.