# ogr2ogr query with " " as separator for the command and within the query results in empty response

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr

With ogr2ogr I query geodata from a postgis database into a Geopackage. The main attribute is "natural" which as to wrappend with " ". The query is wrapped by " ", too. This leads into a empty response / geopackage

The command is:
`ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" natural_EPSG4326.gpkg -nln natural_EPSG4326_point PG:"host=localhost dbname=osmdatabase user=postgres password=*********" -sql "select * from import.osm_point where "natural" <> ''"`

How can I wrap the sql-command for ogr2ogr without " " to query "natural"?

Comment: Here `natural` is not wrapped in double quotes: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/98406/104659

Comment: I'm not talking about QGIS. Please have look at my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679704/regular-query-results-in-syntax-error-with-specific-attribute?noredirect=1#comment101806315_57679704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quote should be escaped:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" natural_EPSG4326.gpkg -nln natural_EPSG4326_point PG:"host=localhost dbname=osmdatabase user=postgres password=*********" -sql "select * from import.osm_point where \"natural\" <> ''"
```